# pjsua_conf_disconnect do not mute mic on some Mac

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, pjsip

**The question:**

Is it possible that under specific condition (hardware, ...) the `pjsua_conf_disconnect(0, callInfo.conf_slot)` function do not mute the mic?

If yes, how can we effectively mute the mic with PJSIP?

**The details:**

In a OSX SIP application, user can mute the mic, and this will call:

```
...
pjsua_call_info callInfo;
pjsua_call_get_info([self identifier], &callInfo);
pj_status_t status = pjsua_conf_disconnect(0, callInfo.conf_slot);
...
```

Where `[self identifier]` is the `pjsua_call_id` of the current call.

I know for sure that after those 3 lines, `status == PJ_SUCCESS`, because only if this condition is true the UI is updated to let the user know the mic is muted.

This project uses the `pjlib 1.12.0 for POSIX` static libs.

Users that face this problem are on Mac OSX 10.8.1 and 10.8.2. They are all using their built-in MacBook [Pro,Air] mic, no headset.

*Note that I am NOT able reproduce this problem myself on an OSX 10.8.2 mid-2009 MBP with the exact same build (from the MacAppStore), this is what making this problem hard to trouble shoot.*

*Note that it is not a random problem, it is contant: as the mute function never works for users experiencing this issue, and it always work for the others.*